# Can fields of the class and arguments of the method interfere?

Tags: java, concurrency, methods, field, visibility

I have a class with a fields called "a". In the class I have a method and in the list of arguments of this method I also have "a". So, which "a" I will see inside of the method? Will it be the field or it will be the argument of the method?

```
public class myClass {
   private String a;
   // Method which sets the value of the field "a".
   public void setA(String a) {
     a = a;
   }
}
```

By the way, there is a similar situation. A method has some local (for method) variables whose names coincide with the names of the fields. What will the "see" the method if I refer to such a method-local variable inside the method (the field or the local variable)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more local scope has the priority, so the parameter `a` will hide the field `a`. In effect, you set the value of parameter `a` to itself. The proper idiom to avoid name clashes (and improve readability) is to use `this` to explicitly mark the class member:

```
public void setA(String a) {
  this.a = a;
}
```

The same is true for local variables vs member variables: local variables hide member variables with the same name.

Comment: And when working with inner-classes you can use `myClass.this.a` to refer to the `myClass` instance.

Answer (score 2):

To add to all the answers recommending:

```
public void setA(String a) {
   this.a = a;
}
```

it's important to realise that omitting the `this` will simply set the parameter to itself. By using `final` thus

```
public void setA(final String a) {
   this.a = a;
}
```

you can eliminate errors caused by omitting `this`. Using `final` is a good practise whenever specifying parameters and fields that aren't intentionally required to change.

Comment: +1 for recommending additional thing instead of writing almost duplicate answer like others

Answer (score 1):

The closest one. That is,

```
 a = a;
```

inside the method has no effect since both refer to the argument a. To refer to the instance variable a you use the this keyword.

```
 this.a = a;
```

Comment: Cool! I did not think about the usage of `this`. I though that I need to rename the argument of the method. But now I think that `this` provide a more elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The local version will "shadow" the instance variable by the same name. One pattern to get around this in accessors like your is this:

```
public void setA(String a) {
   this.a = a;
}
```

which uses the `this` keyword to be explicit about scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` to access the `class` variable, otherwise it will always take the parameter variable.